# Se puede decir en español "desarrollo arrestado" como sinónimo de "desarrollo detenido"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

En Inglés, "arrested development" , (traducido literalmente como desarrollo arrestado) significa desarrollo detenido. En Español, uno de los sinónimos de arrestado es detenido.

[Arrestado](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/arrestado)

Pero nunca en mi vida escuché que alguien dijera "desarrollo arrestado" como sinónimo de "desarrollo detenido", pero si arrestado y detenido realmente son sinónimos debería poderse decir y significar lo mismo, o no?

Se puede decir en español "desarrollo arrestado" como sinónimo de "desarrollo detenido"?

Comment: Pareciera que sí: https://ensuper8.com/index.php/2019/03/18/el-desarrollo-arrestado-debe-terminar-despues-de-la-decepcionante-temporada-5/

Comment: Qué significa "arrested development"? No encuentro nada aparte del título de una serie.

Comment: coincido con @wimi: nunca oí esto. Iría bien que indicaras qué es, aunque sea con un ejemplo claro de uso.

Comment: desarrollo detenido, alguien que no creció fisicamente y también en Inglés veo que lo usan para alguien inmaduro.

Comment: @wimi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrested_development explica su uso en medicina

Comment: Yo creo que el error aquí es que [arrestar](https://dle.rae.es/arrestar#3jkMjo3) y [detener](https://dle.rae.es/detener?m=30_2) se toman de manera general como sinóminos cuando en realidad solo son sinónimos un signficado concreto de cada palabra: el primero de arrestar y el tercero de detener.

Comment: No, lo correcto es **desarrollo detenido**. Aquí detenido toma el significado de que no se le permite seguir avanzando. Arrestado tiene más la acepción de estar en prisión. Y aunque parezca que detenido y arrestado puedan ser semejantes, porque detenido también puede significar en prisión, en este contexto tienen un significado muy diferente.

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta de decirlo sería: **"desarrollo detenido"**, ya que la palabra "arrestado" aunque técnicamente es válida, se asocia más a ser capturado por la policía. De todas formas depende del contexto, por ejemplo:

**"El niño tenía su desarrollo detenido"** Suena correcto y entendible para cualquiera.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Asi expresa lo mismo que en inglés como lo descibe wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

No, `detenido` tiene significado de parar en este caso, `desarrollo arrestado` suena fatal. El significado de `arrestado` que me viene a la mente es cuando un policía arresta a un caco, por ejemplo. Creo que ahí hay un matiz no equivalente en español, luego no te puedo dar un ejemplo porque no hay nada 100% válido, aunque igual algo que se le aproxime.

Comment: Yo tambien creía eso,  pero en el link en español que puse dice sólo que significa detenido, no detenido en una cárcel. Es correcta esa definición o no?

Comment: se entiende por el contexto que arrestado es detenido en una cárcel, mira la RAE que es bastante más de fiar

Comment: La entrada de la RAE no dice nada. ". adj. Audaz, arrojado." https://dle.rae.es/arrestado?m=30_2

Comment: Desafortunadamente Hollywood hace lo que se le da la gana.

Comment: @aparente001 Estoy 100% de acuerdo con lo de que dices que Hollywood hace lo que se le da la gana pero en este caso es un término usado en medicina, antropología y arqueología segun esta wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrested_development

Comment: yo no me fío de la wikipedia... hay malas adaptaciones en IT de lo que son las cosas a sus definiciones